# How to draw a dashed line in a CustomPainter in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-custompainter

There's no native API for drawing a dashed line in Flutter. [An existing snippet](https://coflutter.com/flutter-how-to-draw-dashed-line-on-canvas/) allows drawing horizontal dashed lines but I can't find a snippet for drawing arbitrary dashed line from one point to another. There also exists a library called [dash_painter](https://pub.dev/packages/dash_painter/example) that draws a dashed path. However, I'm only interested in drawing simple dashed lines. In particular, I'm looking for a snippet for drawing dashed lines that's similar to `canvas.drawLine(Offset p1, Offset p2, Paint paint)`.

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/path_drawing/latest/path_drawing/dashPath.html - all you need to do is to call `moveTo` and `lineTo` on your `Path` - it should be faster than multiple calls to `Canvas.drawLine`

Comment: @pskink Thanks for pointing out the path_drawing library and the path commands. Since I'm only drawing a few dashed lines, I think the overhead of drawLine is not very pronounced. If you are interested, feel free to edit my answer to use path commands or provide your own alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function for drawing a dashed line from point p1 to point p2 in a `CustomPainter`:

```dart
void drawDashedLine(
      {required Canvas canvas,
      required Offset p1,
      required Offset p2,
      required int dashWidth,
      required int dashSpace,
      required Paint paint}) {
  // Get normalized distance vector from p1 to p2
  var dx = p2.dx - p1.dx;
  var dy = p2.dy - p1.dy;
  final magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  dx = dx / magnitude;
  dy = dy / magnitude;

  // Compute number of dash segments
  final steps = magnitude ~/ (dashWidth + dashSpace);

  var startX = p1.dx;
  var startY = p1.dy;

  for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    final endX = startX + dx * dashWidth;
    final endY = startY + dy * dashWidth;
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(startX, startY), Offset(endX, endY), paint);
    startX += dx * (dashWidth + dashSpace);
    startY += dy * (dashWidth + dashSpace);
  }
}
```

Example usage: Draw a red dashed line from (0, 0) to (100, 100) with dash width of 6 and spacing of 4.

```
drawDashedLine(
    canvas: canvas,
    start: Offset(0, 0),
    end: Offset(100, 100),
    dashWidth: 6,
    dashSpace: 4,
    paint: Paint()..color = Colors.red..strokeWidth = 1);
```

*EDIT*

this is a version that uses one `Canvas.drawPoints` method call:

```
void drawDashedLine({
  required Canvas canvas,
  required Offset p1,
  required Offset p2,
  required Iterable<double> pattern,
  required Paint paint,
}) {
  assert(pattern.length.isEven);
  final distance = (p2 - p1).distance;
  final normalizedPattern = pattern.map((width) => width / distance).toList();
  final points = <Offset>[];
  double t = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (t < 1) {
    points.add(Offset.lerp(p1, p2, t)!);
    t += normalizedPattern[i++];  // dashWidth
    points.add(Offset.lerp(p1, p2, t.clamp(0, 1))!);
    t += normalizedPattern[i++];  // dashSpace
    i %= normalizedPattern.length;
  }
  canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.lines, points, paint);
}
```

in the most simple form you can call it with `pattern: [20, 10]` but more complex patterns are possible: `pattern: [20, 5, 5, 5]`

Comment: your code does not draw the last segment correctly, see the updated method - try: `final p1 = Offset(100, 100); final p2 = Offset(300, 200); drawDashedLine(canvas: canvas, p1: p1, p2: p2, dashWidth: 20, dashSpace: 10, paint: p);` with your and my version and you will notice the difference on the last drawn segment, you can add `canvas.drawCircle(p2, 8, paint)` to better "see" the line end point

Comment: @pskink Your upated method looks fantastic. I wasn't aware of such functions like `Offset.lerp` and `Offset.distance` so I did the component math by hand.

Comment: indeed, a little bit like reinventing the wheel, now life is simpler :-)

Comment: btw `lerp` method is very handy and is used in many classes like `Rect.lerp`, `Size.lerp`, `Alignment.lerp`, `Color.lerp` and more than 100 other classes